# Problems with R's grep function

Tags: r

I thought I understood well the use of grep, it finds the matches and I create a filter with them, to select or delete the rows that contain the matches. But I have in some cases I don't get the expected result. I give examples:

```
T_fil [grep('\\b(vp)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# ok, leave the row that has vp

T_fil [-grep('\\b(vp)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# ok, remove the ones with vp

T_fil [grep('\\b(q)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# good, don't select any rows because none have q

T_fil [-grep('\\b(q)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# error, it deletes all the rows for me, and I shouldn't delete any, because none have q

T_fil [grep('\\b()\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# good, select all, I don't understand why, but being empty I'm interested in not making any changes

T_fil [-grep('\\b()\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# error, it deletes all the rows and what interests me is that being empty does not make any changes
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me and what can I do to make the result correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that, if `grep` finds no hit, it returns an empty vector. A negative empty vector is *still* an empty vector. You then use that to select rows, and nothing gets selected.

In reality, `grep` is bad for selecting elements for this reason. A better function that works almost the same is `grepl`, which returns a logical vector instead, and the result of which can be inverted with `!`:

```
T_fil [grepl('\\b(q)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# good, don't select any rows because none have q

T_fil [!grepl('\\b(q)\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# good, select all rows
```

Alternatively, you could also pass `invert = TRUE` to `grep` to obtain the same result. That is: **do not use `-grep(…)` to invert the result of a query**, it’s unreliable. Instead, either use `grep(…, invert = TRUE)` or use `!grepl(…)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is almost perfect, except for the following case:
T_fil [!grepl('\\b()\\b', T_fil$Int),] 
# removes all rows, but I want it to leave all rows, because there is no match

Comment: @LauraMS But the regex you’re using *does* match all rows. In fact, I am not clear on what you intend to use the expression `"\\b()\\b"` for, it doesn’t make a whole lot of sense (the query is a convoluted way of saying “match every string” — that’s probably not what you had in mind).

Comment: Rodolfo: Sorry, I wanted to summarize it a lot, but I'll explain '\\b()\\b' corresponds to some cells of a data frame that are empty, there is no value. This filter is applied to the entire data frame, and some of these cells are empty, so I need that in these cases no row is really deleted.

Comment: In that case, you need to use a different regex, e.g. `"^$"`.